# Web part async postback getting Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

Tags: sharepoint-2007, updatepanel, web-parts

*Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '
http://servername/ScriptResource.axd?d=EltQ7pexCbRndWc7D3a....b2a49de
Line: 5*

I recently converted a SmartPart + UserControl web part to a *'real'* web part. The user control part remained essentially unchanged and contains an UpdatePanel. The aim is to have an interactive calendar control which updates its own data but does not cause a full page refresh. The main reason for converting to a real web part is to make use of personal storage so that users can choose a particular setting and store it.

The problem I now have is that when one of the LinkButtons in my web part are clicked I get the error listed above. I am not doing any Response.Writes and there don't seem to be any HttpHeader entries in IIS.

Can anyone help here? Thanks.

**New clue**
Just noticed that the postback events work when the page is checked out but not when it has been published. What is the significance of this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the sharepoint script manager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

It sounds like a HttpModule is altering the json postback of the update panel

Comment: +1 for replying. I have the ScriptManager on the master page but not the SafeScriptManager. I tried to add it to my **control ascx** but can't find the reference to Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport. Note that it does actually work while in checked-out mode but not once the page has been published